# No longer able to save an individual photo downloaded from iCloud onto my Windows 10 PC hard drive: Microsoft Photos opens the image automatically

Tags: windows-10, images, download, photos, icloud

I used to be able to download individual images from iCloud to my Windows 10 PC, but recently Microsoft Photos has begun to intercept the downloaded file and open the photo automatically, and then, when I try to save the image to disk from within that app, zero bytes get saved. The workaround is to download several images, which iCloud puts into a ZIP file. But is there a way to change this default behavior of Microsoft Photos in Windows 10?

Comment: Download the photos to a different folder that Photos does not normally use. I log into to iCloud to download pictures and that is how I do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm already doing that.  It  all started after a recent Windows update but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: I have all my Windows updates done here.

Comment: I'm saving the file to a folder on my H: drive, not to Pictures or any folder that Photos would "normally use".  It is as if there is a listener on the file system that is intercepting the jpg file and sending it to Photos.